# How to delete from the DATABASE a collection by removing the parent object?

Tags: jpa, sql-delete, cascade

I have an object that contains a collection. And i want to delete all objects in this collection after removing the parent object.

Here is my model Ressource

```
@Entity
public class Ressource implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long idt_ressource;
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private String telephone;
    private String matricule;
    private String mail;
    private Date dateEntree;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="ressource")
    private Collection<Affectation> affectations;

    // Getters, Setters and Construct
}
```

And here is my model Affectation

```
@Entity
public class Affectation implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long idt_affectation;
    private Date dateDebut;
    private Date dateFin;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idt_ressource")
    private Ressource ressource;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idt_structure")
    private Structure structure;

    // Getters, Setters and Construct 
}
```

Comment: Please correct the question : delete from the DATABASE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="ressource")
   private Collection<Affectation> affectations;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I forgot forgotten the option cascade. the errors of begginers :D